# Azure Devops: Selecting which variable group to use at the stage level

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration

Just for the sake of cleaner code, it would be nice if I could only introduce variable groups in when they are needed. Currently in my yaml file, I've got 3 stages each with a condition attached to them (where only 1 stage will be run each build). Each stage has its own variable group that is only relevant to that stage. When I try to define the variable groups at each stage it doesn't work, and I get an error saying that the variable can't be accessed. This goes away when I define all the groups at the root level.

Is there any way that I can define which variable groups are used at the stage level.?

Essentially this is what I have right now:

```
variables:
- group: variable-group-1 
- group: variable-group-2
- group: variable-group-3
- name: some-other-variable
  value: some-value

stages: 
- stage: A
  condition: ...
  jobs:
  - job: A1
  - job: A2

- stage: B
  condition: ...
  jobs:
  - job: B1
  - job: B2

- stage: C
  condition: ...
  jobs:
  - job: C1
  - job: C2
```

And this is what I would like:

```
variables:
- name: some-other-variable
  value: some-value

stages: 
- stage: A
  condition: ...
  variables:
  - group: variable-group-1 
  jobs:
  - job: A1
  - job: A2

- stage: B
  condition: ...
  variables:
  - group: variable-group-2
  jobs:
  - job: B1
  - job: B2

- stage: C
  condition: ...
  variables:
  - group: variable-group-3
  jobs:
  - job: C1
  - job: C2
```

**EDIT**

This is a simple version of my yaml that is still failing:

```
trigger:
- '*'

pool:
  vmImage: macOS-latest

variables:
  - name: sdk
    value: 'iphoneos'
  - name: signingIdentity
    value: 'iPhone Distribution'

stages:
- stage: dev_stage
  variables:
  - group: iOS-dev-pipeline
  - name: configuration
    value: 'Debug'
  jobs:
  - job: dev_build_sign
    steps:
    - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
      name: debugConfig
      displayName: 'Download debug config'
      inputs:
        secureFile: '$(appConfig)'
```

The error that I am getting when I run this is:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNugV.png)

And this shows the group is available to all pipelines, and contains appConfig
[Variable Group Declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96xCI.png)

The secure file is also available to all pipelines, same as the group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can recreate the same issue.  The problem appears to be that the variable is not being dereferenced, and instead is being taken literally.  It appears that it is not possible to use a variable scoped at the stage for referencing a secure file.  When the pipeline is run, it looks like the secure file download is performed as a pre-job step, so I'm guessing it is performed before the stage variables are evaluated.

The issue appears to be related to this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/6885).  Although this refers to the classic UI, it appears to be an issue with YAML based pipelines as well.

I see 3 alternatives which may or may not be appropriate depending on your use case.

1. Use a global scoped variable, which seems to work.

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  - name: secureFileName
    value: test.txt

stages:
- stage: testSecureFileDownload
  variables:
  - group: SecureFileTest
  jobs:
  - job: testSecureFileDownload
    steps:
    - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
      name: secureFileTest
      inputs:
        secureFile: '$(secureFileName)'
```

2. Use a literal value for the secure file name.

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: testSecureFileDownload
  variables:
  - group: SecureFileTest
  jobs:
  - job: testSecureFileDownload
    steps:
    - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
      name: secureFileTest
      inputs:
        secureFile: 'test.txt'
```

3. Pass the secure file name in as a parameter.  Of limited use if the pipeline is auto-triggered.

```
parameters:
  - name: secureFileName
    type: string

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  - name: secureFileName
    value: test.txt

stages:
- stage: testSecureFileDownload
  variables:
  - group: SecureFileTest
  jobs:
  - job: testSecureFileDownload
    steps:
    - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
      name: secureFileTest
      inputs:
        secureFile: ${{ parameters.secureFileName }}
```

Comment: Thanks for this!!! Yeah I’m starting to think my best bet would be to keep everything at the global level. Might be a bit messier but at least it works 

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure Pipeline, in fact we can use the variable under the stage. I create a demo yaml and it works well:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  name: default

variables:
- name: Test_For_ABC
  value: ABC

stages:
  - stage: A
    variables:
    - group: cmt
    jobs:
      - job: A1
        steps:
        - task: PowerShell@2
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              Write-Host "$(dockerhubuser)"
              Write-Host "$(Test_For_ABC)"
  - stage: B
    variables:
    - group: TestGroup
    jobs:
      - job: B1     
        steps:
        - task: PowerShell@2
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              Write-Host "$(ServiceConnection)"
              Write-Host "$(Test_For_ABC)"
```

[image]
[image]

According to your error info, we recommend you can check this information:

1. Please make sure the variables in your variable-group only been used in the same stage.
2. Please check if you have enabled the option 'Allow access to all pipelines' in your variable-group.
3. Also, you can create two new variable-groups and use my test yaml to try again.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I am still having the same issues. I have updated my question with information on what I have done, and that I have followed your steps and they are still not working. Do you see anything that I have missed?

Comment: The difference is that it is different tasks. I have the same issue and it's possible to use variables in bash scripts, but not to access a key vault. Maybe certain things are evaluated in an earlier/later stage and thus are not available.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the variable group, it's the secure file that you are referencing in the following line:

```
secureFile: '$(appConfig)'
```

Within Azure Devops, navigate to Pipelines -> Library, and then select the "Secure files" tab.  Edit the file referenced by the `appConfig` variable, and  enable the "Authorize for use in all pipelines option.

Or click on the "Authorize resources" button in the error message that you are getting to authorise the secure file with just that pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I said in my question, the appConfig secure file is available to all pipelines. Clicking on the Authorise Resources button seems to just spit out the same error over and over again.

Comment: Sorry, yes you did mention that the secure file was available to all pipelines.  I was focusing too much on your screenshots.  I've posted an alternative answer which I hope explains the problem.